# Error playing back video uploaded via PhoneGap FileTransfer

Tags: android, cordova, video, phonegap-plugins, file-transfer

I've been stuck on this issue for awhile and i can't seem to find a solution. What i am trying to achieve is this:

1. Select a video from the phone's library
2. Upload the video to Amazon AWS using a signed PUT url
3. Download the uploaded video and play it back on the PC

I am able to select the video from the phone's gallery and successfully upload it to Amazon aws. However, when i try to open and playback the file, media player says that the file format is not supported.

It cannot be a codec issue with my player because i can playback other videos that were uploaded to amazon (via standard HTML file input). Plus, when i transfer the same video from my phone to the desktop, it is playable.

I have a feeling that i'm missing out something when setting up the FileTransfer object. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(
function(imgUrl) {
    that.mDialogOpen("Uploading video...");
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imgUrl, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function(file) {
            var parts       = fileEntry.nativeURL.split('/');
            var filename    = parts[parts.length - 1];

            // Params is sent to the server to generate the signed amazon put url
            var params      = {'a':'handlerFunctionKey', 'name':filename, 'type':'multipart/encrypted'};

            var callback = function(data) {
                alert("In callback");
                var dataResp = data['handlerFunctionKey'];
                if (dataResp.status == 'SUCCESS') {
                    var amazonUrl = decodeURIComponent(dataResp.object);

                    alert("Setting up options: " + file.type);
                    var ftOptions           = new FileUploadOptions();
                    ftOptions.fileName      = filename;
                    ftOptions.mimeType      = file.type;
                    ftOptions.chunkedMode   = false;
                    ftOptions.headers       = {'Content-Type':"multipart/encrypted",'x-amz-acl':'public-read',"Connection":"close"};
                    ftOptions.httpMethod    = 'PUT';

                    var ft = new FileTransfer();
                    ft.upload(imgUrl, amazonUrl, 
                    function() {
                        $("#mModalText").html("Upload success");
                    }, 
                    function(err) {
                        alert("Upload error: " + err.code);
                        alert("Upload target: " + err.target);
                        alert("Upload source: " + err.source);
                    }, ftOptions, true);
                }
            };

            that.doAjax(params, callback); // Execute ajax call to server and run the callback function upon response
        }, function() {});
    }, function() {});
},
function() {}, options);
```

The 'options' for the getPicture function are:

```
var options = {quality:50, destinationType:Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI};
options['sourceType']   = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
options['mediaType']    = Camera.MediaType.VIDEO;
options['targetWidth']  = 640;
options['targetHeight'] = 480;
```

The video i'm uploading is a MP4 with mimeType 'video/mp4'. I'm testing this on an Android. I'm building the code with Phonegap version 6.0.1 via remote build.

Thanks in advance.